# Lua - Simple Modulo issue and variable changing

Tags: lua, while-loop, boolean, modulus

I'm here starting to learn Lua, and I made a simple loop to understand this. It's supposed to print out 10-100 by seeing every number 1-100 that has a remainder of zero with modulus.

The code is as follows:

```
i=1
while i<=100
    do i = i+1
    if i%10 == 0 then
        print(i)
    end
end
```

I expect the output to be:
    10
    20
    30
    40
    50
    60
    70
    80
    90
    100

Instead, the output is this:
    20
    30
    40
    50
    60
    70
    80
    90
    100
    true

I have no idea why 10 isn't getting printed, and I have no real idea when i turned into "true".
I'm using Lua 5.1 with SciTE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code [appears](http://ideone.com/5g5KM) to work in ideone, so I'm guessing it's a problem with SciTE.

Comment: The code works fine in the [live demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html).

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine with ScITE and 5.1 for me.